# Simular a mesma SQL no Entity Framework com Linq e Lambda?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Tendo esse modelo de dados quero gerar uma [**SQL**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) dessa forma no Entity Framework com [**Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) e [**Lambda**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397687.aspx)?

***Dados de suporte***

```sql
SELECT 
    Pessoa.PessoaId, 
    Pessoa.Nome, 
    Pessoa.PessoaPaiId,
    PessoaPai.Nome AS NomePai, 
    Pessoa.PessoaMaeId,
    PessoaMae.Nome AS NomeMae
FROM Pessoa 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pessoa AS PessoaPai on Pessoa.PessoaPaiId = PessoaPai.PessoaId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pessoa AS PessoaMae on Pessoa.PessoaMaeId = PessoaMae.PessoaId
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Resultado esperado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para gerar esse tipo de SQL deve usar os métodos [**GroupJoin**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx) com [**SelectMany**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) para ter o mesmo efeito da SQL pedida. Os exemplos abaixo comprova a geração da mesma SQL, observe:

***Linq***

```
using (ObjEntities cx = new ObjEntities())
{
    var resultLinq = (from pessoa in cx.Pessoa
                      join pessoapai in cx.Pessoa on pessoa.PessoaPaiId equals pessoapai.PessoaId into Pai
                      from P in Pai.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join pessoamae in cx.Pessoa on pessoa.PessoaMaeId equals pessoamae.PessoaId into Mae
                      from M in Mae.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          pessoa.PessoaId,
                          pessoa.Nome,
                          pessoa.PessoaPaiId,
                          NomePai = P.Nome,
                          pessoa.PessoaMaeId,
                          NomeMae = M.Nome
                      })
                      .ToList();

}
```

***Lambda:***

```
using (ObjEntities cx = new ObjEntities())
{
    var resultLambda = cx.Pessoa
        .GroupJoin(cx.Pessoa, pessoa => pessoa.PessoaPaiId, pessoapai => pessoapai.PessoaId, (pessoa, pessoapai) => new { pessoa, pessoapai })
        .SelectMany(a => a.pessoapai.DefaultIfEmpty(), (c, d) => new
        {
            c.pessoa.PessoaId,
            c.pessoa.Nome,                        
            NomePai = d.Nome,
            c.pessoa.PessoaPaiId, 
            c.pessoa.PessoaMaeId
        })
        .GroupJoin(cx.Pessoa, pessoa => pessoa.PessoaMaeId, pessoamae => pessoamae.PessoaId, (pessoa, pessoamae) => new { pessoa, pessoamae }) 
        .SelectMany(b => b.pessoamae.DefaultIfEmpty(), (e, f) => new {
            e.pessoa.PessoaId, 
            e.pessoa.Nome, 
            e.pessoa.PessoaPaiId, 
            NomePai = e.pessoa.NomePai,
            e.pessoa.PessoaMaeId,
            NomeMae = f.Nome
        })
        .ToList();          
}
```

A geração da SQL dos dois tipos de estilo de codificação é igual a da pergunta:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PessoaId] AS [PessoaId], 
[Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome], 
[Extent1].[PessoaPaiId] AS [PessoaPaiId], 
[Extent2].[Nome] AS [Nome1], 
[Extent1].[PessoaMaeId] AS [PessoaMaeId], 
[Extent3].[Nome] AS [Nome2]
FROM   [dbo].[Pessoa] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Pessoa] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PessoaPaiId] = [Extent2].[PessoaId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Pessoa] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[PessoaMaeId] = [Extent3].[PessoaId]
```

***Debug***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Referências:***

- [How to: Perform Grouped Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx)
- [Método Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx)